# Groovy inspect() handle dollar sign($)

Tags: groovy, inspect, dollar-sign

below code can not run

```
def map = [name:"Test :: ( %2f %25 \$ * & ! @ # ^)"]
String s = map.inspect()
println Eval.me(s)
```

get error:

```
Script1.groovy: 1: illegal string body character after dollar sign; 

solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 1, column 30.
   ["name":"Test :: ( %2f %25 $ * & ! @ # ^)"]
```

but if string contain other special char like \", it works correctly. any way, how to walk around? it's emergency for me

Comment: I tried what you are doing.  You may very well have found a bug within Groovy's inspect method.  *However*, that being said, **what are you really trying to accomplish?**  The `Eval` method should never be used the way you are showing there - it's kind of a general rule that [eval is evil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) (yes, that's JS but the same issues apply to all dynamic languages).

Comment: We want to transfer data between two computers. The data structure is Map, so I call inspect() in one computer and pass the string to the other computer, it call eval.me to re-build Map structure

Comment: OK, see below for my response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle Copy files and expand only some of them and/or ignore dollar signs in others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25152045/gradle-copy-files-and-expand-only-some-of-them-and-or-ignore-dollar-signs-in-oth)

Comment: See my response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25152045/gradle-copy-files-and-expand-only-some-of-them-and-or-ignore-dollar-signs-in-oth/42395410#42395410

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(In response to follow up above)*

OK, if you just want to exchange information, then you should use a Data Interchange Format, such as XML or JSON.  I recommend JSON because it's lightweight, fast, and *really* easy to use:

*Computer 1*

```
def map = [name:"Test :: ( %2f %25 \$ * & ! @ # ^)"]
def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
json(map)
println json.toString()
```

*Computer 2*

```
def incoming = '{"name":"Test :: ( %2f %25 $ * & ! @ # ^)"}'
def jsonInput = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def map = jsonInput.parseText(incoming)
println map
```

Please note that these require Groovy 1.8.0 or newer to function.  There are plenty of examples for older versions of Groovy, and Grails has it's own parsers built-in as well.

Comment: More on Groovy 1.8's JSON objects: http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/json/package-summary.html

Comment: More on Grails built-in JSON and XML convertors: http://grails.org/Converters+Reference

Comment: Yes, we have change it to XML. Seem JSON is better, I will consider your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes round your string:

```
def map = [name:'Test :: ( %2f %25 \$ * & ! @ # ^)']
```

When you use double quotes, the [dollar char is used for templating](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString)

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is the string is not created by me, it's created by the inspect() method.even I define map as you said, when call inspect() method, groovy will convert the string to "Test :: ( %2f %25 $ * & ! @ # ^)"

Comment: @Xilang Can you try using the [dollar-slash string delimiter](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/04/groovy-goodness-new-dollar-slashy.html) like: `def map = [name:$/Test :: ( %2f %25 \$ * & ! @ # ^)/$]`?

Comment: Our project use groovy 1.7.8, so sad

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes and a double backslash ,like,

```
def map = [name:'Test :: ( %2f %25 \\$ * & ! @ # ^)']
String s = map.inspect()
println Eval.me(s)
```

Comment: But 'Test :: ( %2f %25 \\$ * & ! @ # ^)' is not the string I want. I want string $ not \$.

Comment: After the .inspect(), you will get the string you wanted. If you want string $, then def map = [name:'Test :: ( %2f %25 \$ * & ! @ # ^)']. If you want \$, then def map = [name:'Test :: ( %2f %25 \\$ * & ! @ # ^)']  .Anyway, it looks like you are considering an XML/JSON solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the following and it worked for me

```
> a = ["guy":"mogr \$ abi"]
Eval.me(a.inspect())["guy"]
mogr $a bi
```