# Gradle Copy files and expand only some of them and/or ignore dollar signs in others

Tags: gradle

I have a tree of files that I'd like to copy with Gradle, and for some of the files (e.g. ending in .txt), I'd like to do some property substitions.  For example, I have:

```
task "copyAndroidAssets$flavor" (type: Copy, 
   dependsOn: ["cleanAndroidAssets", "copyAndroidRes$flavor"] ) {
   from "build/assets/${flavorLc}/release/"
   into '../android/assets'
   expand ( versionName: myVersionName, versionCode: myVersionCode )
}
```

The problem is that some of the files in the tree being copied have dollar signs ($) in them that have nothing to do with property expansion, and this creates the error `SimpleTemplateScript6.groovy: 1: illegal string body character after dollar sign;`.

In my specific scenario, all the files except one can simply be copied as is. Only a single file, `about.txt`, needs to have values substituted. Any suggestions on a simple way to do this?

Comment: Maybe instead of `expand` method use `filter` with `ReplaceTokens`? Have a look at API doc, there's an example included: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Copy.html

Comment: Yes, I wondered about that. I was hoping though that there was a way to only expand for a given filename / filetype. I want to avoid an accidental expansion of the other files if possible. I'll give it a try. I'm thinking eachFile() might have a way, but I'm unsure how to add expand() treatment from within that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Now (Gradle 2.3.1) there is a better solution: https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1566

```
processResources {
    inputs.property('version', version)
    filesMatching("**/version.properties") {
        expand version: version
    } }
```

In my case I want project properties expansion only in yaml files:

```
processResources {
    filesMatching("**/*.yaml") {
        expand project.properties
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the link from Opal in the comments, I found a solution. The link shows that **it is possible to have multiple `from` sources** and **each of these can have a separate `expand` treatment**. Thus, in my case, I only wanted to expand `.txt` files, so I split the `from` into two parts using `include` & `exclude` as follows:

```
task "copyAndroidAssets$flavor" (type: Copy, 
    dependsOn: ["cleanAndroidAssets", "copyAndroidRes$flavor"] ) {
    from ("build/assets/${flavorLc}/release/") {
        include '**/*.txt'
        expand ( versionName: versionName, versionCode: versionCode )
    }
    from ("build/assets/${flavorLc}/release/") {
        exclude '**/*.txt'
    }
    into '../android/assets'
    expand ( versionName: myVersionName, versionCode: myVersionCode )
}
```