# Need a gradle jar task that copies classes normally and custom files

Tags: gradle

In my Gradle build, after the classes are compiled, I need to create a jar containing the classes in the typical location, but I also need the jar to include a set of other plain text files from a specific subdirectory of the project, and going into a different named folder in the jar.

So, for instance, at the root of the jar, I'll have the "com" folder that starts the classes tree, but I'll also have a "META-INF" folder which contains a custom subfolder name, containing the files copied from the project.

**Update**:

I tried adding the following:

```
jar {
    from ("src/main/resources/yang") {
        into ("META-INF/yang")
    } 
}
```

This comes close to working properly.  It does copy all the files from that "from" folder" to the "into" folder in the resulting jar.  However, the resulting jar ALSO has a "yang" folder containing the same files from "src/main/resources/yang".  So, how do I prevent the default copying of that folder?

I might end up doing this as part of a custom plugin, but for now I'd like to see if I can configure a simple "jar" task to do this.

**Update**:

Based on the solution, the following worked:

```
jar {
    exclude "yang"
    from ("src/main/resources/yang") {
        into ("META-INF/yang")
    } 
}
```

Comment: You can add that subdirectory to the `sourcesets.main.resources.srcDirs` or add a `jar` task dependency on a `copy` task if you need to change the directory layout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle Copy files and expand only some of them and/or ignore dollar signs in others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25152045/gradle-copy-files-and-expand-only-some-of-them-and-or-ignore-dollar-signs-in-oth)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood `build.gradle` can be modified in the following way:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

jar {
    from('other') {
        into('META-INF/other')
    }
}
```

Full demo can be found [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/29156742)

**UPDATE**

This should work:

apply plugin: 'java'

```
jar {
   from('src/main/resources/other') {
      into('META-INF/other')
   }
   exclude 'other/**'
}
```

Comment: This comes close.  I added an update that shows what I added and what the results were.

Comment: Scratch that.  I didn't have the "excludes" clause.  I didn't end up needing the "/**" part, but this worked.